# Saving entries in admin panel

Tags: entry, saving

I have a problem with the admin panel being very slow when saving an entry. It takes about 30 seconds to save an entry. I use a matrix for the different part of the entry (imgs, textfields, titles and so on). Does anyone else have this problem, and have someone found a solution for this? :)

Comment: I have one site hosted on Dreamhost and it does this and I can't figure out why. It's only for entries too. Globals seem to save fine.

Answer (score 1):

To debug where the delay is, you can enable [devMode](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#devMode), which will write out a bunch of code and database profiling information to your log files in `craft/storage/runtime/logs`.

After you do that, save an entry then find that request in the log files.  You can look at the timestamps on that request to see what part of the code the 30 second delay is occurring on, which will point you in the direction of the underlying problem.