# Slow saving when devMode false, but not while true

Tags: devmode, saving

All of a sudden, saving entries became really slow (up to a minute). Regardless of entry type.

I came across this question: [Saving entries in admin panel](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9273/saving-entries-in-admin-panel)

Problem is when I turn on devMode saving goes without a problem and only takes a second, so I am unable to debug it.

Does anyone know why saving all of a sudden is very slow, and/or why saving is fast only with devMode true?

Comment: That's weird... I suppose I'd start by disabling any plugins to try and narrow things down a bit.

Comment: I have tried disabling all the plugins (2), but there is noe difference. There must be something disabled when devMode is true, which causes the delay in production? Everything else works just perfect, also saving globals. Just not saving entries.

Comment: I cleared all caches and updated file index, and now everything runs smooth. No idea why, but it fixed the problem.

Comment: Really weird... can you add that as an official answer?

Answer (score 1):

I cleared all caches and updated file index, and now everything runs smooth. No idea why, but it fixed the problem.

Comment: A few days went by where everything worked as normal. Then today it started to get real slow again. So I cleared all caches and things go smooth again. So my problem seems related to caching in some way. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this yet?

Comment: @EspenSandberg please update if you find the issue!